# how to post date in json object to database through web services

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, http-post

I  post date in json object through web services in database,date stored in database in dateTime format ,I got error 400 bad request

```
  var BBOrderBlood = {};
  BBOrderBlood.BloodIssueDate = '2016-02-15';
 $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ ob: BBOrderBlood }),
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain:true,
                success: function (data) {

                },

            });
```

Comment: why your url is empty?

Comment: What does the server-side look like? Is it expecting a JSON object or a string (currently you're passing a string)? Have you just removed the URL for security or have you really missed it from your code? If you're getting a 400 error, your data is probably getting nowhere near the database, so I don't think that's a factor. Something is going wrong before that step.

Comment: "Is it expecting a JSON object or a string (currently you're passing a string)?" — JSON *has* to be represented as a string in JavaScript. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: We can't tell why the server is telling you it is a bad request without knowing a lot more about the server.